# How to include a shared C library in a Python package

Tags: python, makefile, setuptools

I have a project depending on a shared library. To make it clear from the beginning: the shared library is a pure C library and not a Python library. For reasons of simplicity I created a small demo project called *pkgtest* which I will refer to.

So what needs to be done is: Run a Makefile to compile the library and place the compiled shared library (called `libhello.so` here) file somewhere it can be accessed from within the depending Python package.

My best guess so far was to run the makefile as a preinstallation routine, copy the `libhello.so` file in the packages directory and add it to the `package_data` parameter of the setup script. When installed the shared library then gets placed in the `site-packages/pkgtest/` directory and can be accessed from the module.

The package directory is structure is as simple as this:

```
pkgtest/
  src/
     libhello.c
     libhello.h
     Makefile
  pkgtest/
    __init__.py
    hello.py
  setup.py
```

My setup.py looks like this:

*setup.py*

```
import subprocess
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.command.install import install as _install


class install(_install):
    def run(self):
        subprocess.call(['make', 'clean', '-C', 'src'])
        subprocess.call(['make', '-C', 'src'])
        _install.run(self)


setup(
    name='pkgtest',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='stefan',
    packages=['pkgtest'],
    package_data={'pkgtest': ['libhello.so']},
    cmdclass={'install': install},
)
```

The Makefile actually builds the library and copies it into the directory of my python package.

*src/Makefile*

```
all: libhello.so

libhello.o: libhello.c
        gcc  -fPIC -Wall -g -c libhello.c

libhello.so: libhello.o
        gcc -shared -fPIC -o libhello.so libhello.o
        cp libhello.so ../pkgtest/libhello.so

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so
```

So all `hello.py` is actually doing is load the library and call the `hello` function that prints some text. But for completeness I will show the code here:

*pkgtest/hello.py*

```
import os
import ctypes

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
libpath = os.path.join(basedir, 'libhello.so')

dll = ctypes.CDLL(libpath)

def say_hello():
    dll.hello()
```

So this actually works but what I don't like about this approach is that the shared library lives in the directory of the Python package. I figure it would be better to put it in some sort of central library directory such as */usr/lib/*. But for this one would need root privileges on installation. Has somebody got some experience with this kind of problem and would like to share a solution or helpful idea. Would be great.

Comment: Have you considered using a package manager like [conda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)? You could create a separate package for your library and for the Python code, and specify the library as a dependency of the Python code in the `meta.yaml` file.

Comment: I didn't think about conda, yet. You are right, this would definetly be an option, however not my first choice as I want the package to be available via `pip install ...`.

Comment: In that case, I don't think having a compiled library file inside your python package folder is a problem. That's where [Python extension modules](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html) and [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/index.html) modules are placed. But maybe there's a better solution...

Comment: I see no reason why to have a Makefile in the first place. Simple C object files can be compiled and installed by setuptools and the like automatically. See [https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html](here).

Comment: I use the library above only for example. The actual library is more complex with multiple source files and linking. I didn't see how to to this with setuptools.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31380578/1959808

Comment: Consider doing this entirely with [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can create a Python package which includes shared libraries and works on (almost) any linux distro using [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux).

> The goal of the manylinux project is to provide a convenient way to distribute binary Python extensions as wheels on Linux. This effort has produced [PEP 513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) which defines the `manylinux1_x86_64` and `manylinux1_i686` platform tags.

The general procedure is:

1. Build the external library and the Python package inside one of the docker containers provided by the manylinux team
   (see [python-manylinux-demo](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo))
2. Run [`auditwheel repair`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/auditwheel) to copy the external shared libraries that your package depends on into the Python wheel, setting the RPATH accordingly.

See [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo/blob/master/.travis.yml) and [`build-wheels.sh`](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo/blob/master/travis/build-wheels.sh) in the `python-manylinux-demo` repo for an example.

Comment: This looks great. If I get it right the example shows how to build a Python C extension and include that in the wheel. As stated in the question the aim is not to build a Python C extension but build and include a pure C shared library. I still can't figure out how to manage that.

Comment: @MrLeeh : I am also searching solution to almost identical solution (Fortran instead of C). Have you found a workaround?

Comment: What is the process to include internal [instead of external] shared libraries in the `bdist_wheel`?

Answer (score 1):

`package_data` is for data. `setup` can do the compilation into an `*.so`.

Following my solution in [python setup.py build ctypes.CDLL: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434262), I think your `setup` could employ `ext_modules` and `py_modules`, something like

```
setup(name='pkgtest',
      py_modules=['pkgtest'],
      ext_modules=[Extension('src.libhello', ['src/libhello.c'])]
     )
```

Comment: why use `py_modules`? shouldn't it be `packages`?