# Packaging Python with compiled Julia?

Tags: python, julia, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I am working on a python package that relies heavily on a Julia library. Rather than use PyCall, we actually compile the Julia code down into shared objects `.so` files using `PackageCompiler.jl`. It is referenced using `ctypes` in the python module. It also requires a Julia systemimage.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to package this? I know that you can build C/C++ inside of `distutils`, but I haven't really found a good venue for including Julia across multiple platforms.

To be clear here, for someone to use this Python package they need a Julia installation and they need the appropriate shared object libraries for their system. Those can be gotten by running the Julia compiler `juliac.jl`. Everything else is in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a shared C library in a Python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121352/how-to-include-a-shared-c-library-in-a-python-package)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+distribute+shared+library

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using setup.py to build your library, you need to add the shared library(s) to `package_data` when calling `setup()`:

setup.py

```
# call out to build system to build the shared library

setup(
  name="my-extension",
  ext_modules="..."
  package_data="/path/to/mylib.so"
)
```

See further documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

After running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to create a .whl file, you may also want to run [auditwheel](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel), which will compatibility tag (e.g. manylinux1) and isolate (rename with hash, fix-up linkages) the shared libraries.