# How to build a python extension with C++ and include .so files in wheel

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I can't find any instructions on how you would put shared libraries used by python bindings generated with something like pybind11 into a wheel so that the end user does not have to also use an other package manager like apt to install the .so files gnerated in a project.  As an example, if my C++ project builds lib_a.so and lib_b.so as well as python bindings to both - say lib_bindings_ab.so, right now I have to create a debian package to install lib_a.so and lib_b.so, then pip install a wheel with lib_bindings_ab.so.  How do I put lib_a.so and lib_b.so into the wheel, so my end user does not have to use apt and pip - just pip?  I can't find any docs or answers - they are usually just use apt and pip.  That shouldn't be necessary though.  Any pointers?  Google searches not giving me much.

Comment: This can be achieved using the `auditwheel repair` tool from `manylinux`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307507/1118576