# How to cross compile Python packages with PIP?

Tags: python, c++, linux, pip, cross-compiling

Is it possible to cross-compile Python packages using PIP?

I'm trying to install several Python packages containing significant portions of C/C++ (scipy/numpy/matplotlib/pynacl) on a Raspberry Pi. Installing these packages on an x86 machine takes under a minute, but because the Pi is so underpowered, and there are no pre-compiled binary packages for ARM, it takes the Pi a couple hours to compile and install everything.

Is there anyway to compile and install these packages into a special virtualenv on an x86 machine, but targeting the ARM platform, and then rsync the virtualenv onto the Pi? Both the Pi and x86 are running Ubuntu 16.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614261/1032785 mentions this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distutilscross

Comment: Building on raspberry pi might be faster with an USB drive or NFS mounts (maybe nfs root).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at proot. It is made for such things as you describe:

https://proot-me.github.io/