# "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Upon testing my lambda function I get the following error message:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

I uploaded a `.zip` which only includes the following dependancies: `requests`, `boto3`, `PIL`, `Pillow-4.0.0.dist-info` & the lambda function `lambda_function.py` - which is a copied example from AWS:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        image.thumbnail(tuple(x / 2 for x in image.size))
        image.save(resized_path)

def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}resized'.format(bucket), key)
```

My handler is: `lambda_function.lambda_handler`

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: How are you testing it? Where are you trying to run it? Using AWS Lambda Console?

Comment: Lamda console here: https://i.imgur.com/2ZStsne.png

Comment: lambda_function.lambda_handler or lambda_function.handler? but that doesn't matter if you are running from the console. Let me see

Comment: i see the function name is present as handler, by default, lambda accepts as lambda_handler, can you change it and zip then try ?

Comment: The handler is `lambda_function.lambda_handler` @NoorAliJafri

Comment: Change the file name `lambda_function.py` to `lambda_handler.py`? @GowthamChand

Comment: @Zorgan change the handler name to `lambda_function.handler` or update your code to `def lambda_handler(event, context):` then zip it and upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**:

By default lambda runs the handler with the specific keyword named: *lambda_handler* you can change the handler entry as well in the AWS Lambda console.

[image]

Or you have to change the name of your handler:

```
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
    ,,,

def lambda_handler(event,context):  
    '''
```

You can use custom handler while working with some framework and explicitly mention the handler name.

For example with serverless:

```
your_action:
    handler: path/lambda_function.handler
```

**Secondly**:

part of the issue is that you have to check for the modules you have been importing are included. You have to see a detailed error output for that. The immediate response for your scenario would be: *unable to import lambda_function.*

Checking error log you might see something like this:
***Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named PIL***

You also must checkout this question here regarding [importing PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45473501/6198978)

Comment: I changed the handler entry in the AWS Lambda console to `lambda_function.handler` and I'm still getting the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Press SAVE and then run it

Comment: *from PIL import Image import PIL.Image* removing these two lines work. Now comes to the second part of the problem.

Comment: Check if you have included the module.

Comment: Worked for you?

Comment: I've removed `from PIL import Image import PIL.Image`, re-uploaded, saved, then tested but still getting the same error...not sure why. What do you mean by "Check if you have included the module"?

Comment: Editing the post.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, the detailed error says: `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging'` - however there's no use of `_imaging` in the function.

Comment: I haven't worked with this PIL, so can't tell you more than that.

Comment: Should be easier to fix from here with detailed log - thanks for the help!