# Not able to create boto ses client on AWS Lambda for sending mail

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

my python code is not working on Lambda which actully works well when I run it from my local python environment. Whenever I try to create SES object on Lambda function, I get this error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

Here's my code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    connection = boto.ses.connect_to_region('us-east-1')


    return connection.send_email(
            from_addr,
            subject,
            None,
            to,
            format= format,
            text_body=text,
            html_body=html
        )
```

Is it something related to `boto.ses` not being supported over lambda and I have to use boto3 instead??

This lambda function contains multiple part and at the end I have to create SES object to send mail to my client, but when I try to do that I'm getting this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda\_function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814024/errormessage-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function)

Comment: it's not about the name of function or handler because rest of my code works well on lambda , just when i include SES related code then only i'm facing it

Comment: Everything works smoothly without SES? The answer above can be used for initial diagnostics. Let's dig deeper then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, it is highly recommended to use `boto3`.

The syntax is:

```
import boto3

connection = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1')

response = client.send_email(
    Source='string',
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': [
            'string',
        ],
        'CcAddresses': [
            'string',
        ],
        'BccAddresses': [
            'string',
        ]
    },
    Message={
        'Subject': {
            'Data': 'string',
            'Charset': 'string'
        },
        'Body': {
            'Text': {
                'Data': 'string',
                'Charset': 'string'
            },
            'Html': {
                'Data': 'string',
                'Charset': 'string'
            }
        }
    },
    ReplyToAddresses=[
        'string',
    ],
    ReturnPath='string',
    SourceArn='string',
    ReturnPathArn='string',
    Tags=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    ConfigurationSetName='string'
)
```

See: [SES — Boto 3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email)

Comment: Thanks John, boto3 works well but my question was about boto.ses which i guess is not supported over Lambda. I used above code from AWS doc's which worked well for me :)